# Symmetry of a Rhombohedron

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry, reflection

I am trying to find the symmetry operations of the rhombohedron (Trigonal prism, Trigonal trapezohedral). I've already found this has **12** symmetry operations and **1 is identity** and **4 is for rotational symmetry** (**one 3-fold** symmetry and **three 2-fold** symmetry).

I'm trying to identify other symmetry operations such as plane of symmetry and center of symmetry. My calculations suggest that there is 7 plane of symmetries. (Which I'm unsure of) Can someone help me and point me in the right direction lease?

Comment: I get only 6 planes of symmetry all containing the body diagonal. What is the 7th?

Comment: what about the rectangular plane of symmetry. Where the plane is in the midway of the rhombohedron. ? Or am I visualizing it wrong and it should actually be 1 inversion symmetry/

Comment: Yes, the center is a center of symmetry which is orientation reversing. I suggest you construct a physical model along with the orientation reversed version. Label the vertices, edges and faces.

Comment: I understand it now. There is 6 diagonal plane of symmetries and 1 inversion symmetry. Thank you so much for your comment.